# Generic Error while calculating two computed fields

Tags: python, odoo

I am trying to calculate two computed fields but I get a generic error that says the following:
odoo.tools.convert.ParseError: "Error while validating restrictions."

```
class Document(models.Model):

   _name='project_rc.document'

   _rec_name='tipo_movimiento_id'

   total_document_sale=fields.Float(string="Total sale", compute="_totalsale")

   utility_sale=fields.Float(string="Utility sale", compute="_utilitysale", store=True)

   porcentaje_utility=fields.Float(string="Utility (%)", compute="_porcentajeutility")

  @api.multi
  @api.depends('total_document_sale','utility_sale')
  def _porcentajeutilidad(self):
      if self.total_document_sale > 0 and self.utility_sale > 0:
          self.porcentaje_utility = (self.utility_sale/self.total_document_sale) * 100
```

The code used to divide is the following, what is wrong with the code?

Comment: Could you put the full stacktrace? and are you sure this method is the one causing this error?

Comment: There I added more codido that can be useful. I am sure that this method causes me the error, since if I delete it the system works, but I would like to have it show the percentage

Comment: do you have any constrains on the field? `@api.constrains`

Comment: I don't have any contrains field, just depend.

Comment: Change the name of the class to DocumentCustome for now and if you don't want to  do that comment function and try updating I guess class name can be a problem because the same class name is in python libs and stuff and make sure you have a field named tipo_movimiento_id in your project_rc.document module and also get rid of @api.multi if you are using odoo 13 or just get rid of anyway and  Charif is right you may get keyerror in the pop up if you won't do that

Comment: I removed the api.multi and I still have the same error, i use odoo 12